# Symfony: iterate through json object to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

How can I iterate through each Json object parameters?

I receive Json object as input. How can I either to convert this object to array or iterate through each parameter?

Example:

```
 {
  "firstName": "Jane",
  "lastName": "Dow",
  "aboutMe": "Web developer"
 }
```

In controller is it possible to do something like:

```
//$requestData - decoded json content
foreach ($requestData->data as $param){
        //do smth with each param
}
```

In controller I am not able to decode json file to array, because I receive Json object as an input already.

Comment: you want to iterate over attribute? So firstname is the first eleement of the array, lastname the second etc?

Comment: Casting it to an array might work, like `$array = (array) $requestData->data;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the **JSON String** to array or object. Like this,

```
$json_string="{  "firstName": "Jane",  "lastName": "Dow",  "aboutMe": "Web developer" }";
$json_array=json_decode($json_string,true);
```

`$json_array` will be an array and you can iterate over it just like normally you do in **PHP Array**.

> **json_decode()** accepts second parameter as boolean, which is `false` by default. If it is true **json_decode()** return an array
>   otherwise it returns object.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

---

You can iterate over PHP Object like this,

```
foreach ($requestData as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." =>";
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: That's the trick, I am not receiving Json file as an input, I am receiving decoded Json object. So I can't decode file to array

Comment: Do you have JSON string in the variable ?

Comment: No, only json object. Is it ok to encode it back to json string and decode it to array?

Comment: If it's a JSON object you can directly iterate over it like an array. See my updated answer.